# Improving the speed of XGBoost CV

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, hyperparameter, optimization, boosting

My data set has around 5 mil rows. I intend to use xgb,cv to find optimal no of tress and then use caret wrapper or my own custom hyper-parameter tuning function.

XGBoost's in-built cv itself is taking a long time. I guess other functions will take even more time.

Previsouly I worked on smaller data sets. XGboost ran very fast and smooth.

so far I have tried doing CV by converting training data frame to  sparse matrix, dcgMatrix and several other matrix types. Still it's taking lot of time.

Last resort is to make a validation set and try to use that set for parameter tuning. theoretically this is more sound idea, but I have never tried it so little unsure about this.

what are few ways to deal with large data sets?

Answer (score 7):

The "tricks" I am familiar with are :

**Sparse matrices**, which you already used. However, you need to make sure that the percentage of non zero values in your matrix is low (otherwise, it could actually take longer to run)

**Grow the trees one by one and observe the performance after each batch**

I once used the following (with sklearn's implementation of GBMs)

```
def heldout_auc(model, X_test, y_test):
    score = np.zeros((model.get_params()["n_estimators"],), dtype=np.float64)
    for i, y_pred in enumerate(model.staged_decision_function(X_test)):
        score[i] = auc(y_test, y_pred)
    return score

def cv_boost_estimate(X,y,model,n_folds=3):
    cv = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=11)
    val_scores = np.zeros((model.get_params()["n_estimators"],), dtype=np.float64)
    t = time()
    i = 0
    for train, test in cv:
        i = i + 1
        print('FOLD : ' + str(i) + '-' + str(n_folds))
        model.fit(X.iloc[train,], y.iloc[train])
        val_scores += heldout_auc(model, X.iloc[test,], y.iloc[test])
    val_scores /= n_folds
    return val_scores,(time()-t)
```

**Reduce the number of folds of your CV** (which can harm performance). This is close to what you describe with a validation set : "Last resort is to make a validation set and try to use that set for parameter tuning". However, **I would not recommend this approach**. As boosting involves a lot of parameters, you could easily be trapped in overfitting the validation set.

**Focus on some parameters** Disclaimer, this is highly empirical ! In my experience, the most important parameters are max_depth, $\eta$ and $n_{trees}$. And the last two "work together" : decreasing $\eta$ and increasing $n_{trees}$ can help you improve the performance of the model. Whereas it seems that there is an "optimal" max depth parameter.

The other parameters (colsample_bytree, subsample) are usually less relevant.

**Have a look at the python implementation** I observed a better usage of my processors with python than with R. Maybe this has been fixed since though...

Comment: There are some Zeros , but not too many. I have tired building tress one by one. I know how to build `xgboost` trees one by one., but how do we do the same for `xgb.cv`? this I don't know. `xgboost` gives 'model handler' as output where as `xgb.cv` gives data-frame as out put. is it possible to `predict()` and `setinfo()` on `xgb.cv`?

Comment: @Jack maybe you could rewrite a cross validation loop in R. But they are tremendously slow... I would definitely have a look at python (it really does not require a great deal of code)

Comment: Another trick to add is the `colsample_by*` parameters reduce the time taken to fit by roughly what they're set to. So `colsample_bytree = 0.5` will fit roughly twice as fast.